# "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when adding javascript to vue component <script> tag

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error when trying to add the code to auto expand text boxes - from this codepen: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD.
Do I need to add it in a different way?
It's currently in between the script tags in a vue component file.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at eval (Pastes.vue?58dd:23)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/pages/pastes/Pastes.vue (app.js:782)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (Pastes.vue?fa7c:1)
    at Object../src/components/pages/pastes/Pastes.vue (app.js:1220)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (index.js?3672:1)
    at Object../src/router/index.js (app.js:1252)
```

Comment: Note in the Pen Settings -> JS tab it includes `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're loading the jquery library, You can follow this [guide](https://medium.com/code4mk-org/how-to-use-jquery-inside-vue-add-other-js-library-inside-vue-9eea8fbd0416) or this [one](https://tkacz.pro/integrate-jquery-with-vue-js/).

Answer (score 0):

I used this code instead which works pretty well

https://jsfiddle.net/cferdinandi/mqwwpL6u/

```
var autoExpand = function (field) {

    // Reset field height
    field.style.height = 'inherit';

    // Get the computed styles for the element
    var computed = window.getComputedStyle(field);

    // Calculate the height
    var height = parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('border-top-width'), 10)
                 + parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('padding-top'), 10)
                 + field.scrollHeight
                 + parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'), 10)
                 + parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width'), 10);

    field.style.height = height + 'px';

};

document.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'textarea') return;
    autoExpand(event.target);
}, false);
```